# Can't install Windows Server 2016 due to error: Could not open Root directory: [14] Not Found

Tags: windows, boot, windows-server-2016, dualboot

I am trying to install Windows Server 2016. I have used Rufus to create a bootable USB, but when I try and boot from the USB, it gives me the following error: `Could not open Root directory: [14] Not Found`. Attached is an image of the full error message. Does anyone know what I could do?

[image]

Update: After following @Akeo's solution, I now get this error message:[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is not accessible.  Please use the upload image functionality instead.  We also need to know what settings within Rufus you used exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound I unfortunately cannot attach the screenshot due to it being 3.3MB. In Rufus, I selected UEFI/NTFS.

Comment: @Ramhound Here is another link to the screenshot. https://resizeimage.net/viewimg/ZoipHCk0G6CIa2wp/IMAbd/20200625_142816.jpg It is very hard for me to upload the resized image since I am on mobile (computer cannot currently be used)

Comment: I have uploaded hundreds of images on my mobile phone.  All you have to do it hit the button and provide the link the image.  I just took your original linked and uploaded the image for you.  In the future you should do this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rufus and [UEFI:NTFS](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs) author here (which is what Rufus uses to boot images that contain a file that is larger than 4 GB, like the ones found on modern Windows ISOs).

The error you get comes from UEFI:NTFS, and can be explained by the 2 warnings you see:

1. `[WARN]   An NTFS service is already loaded` means that your motherboard's UEFI firmware **already** provides an NTFS driver, and therefore the NTFS driver that Rufus would normally use can not be loaded because it would conflict with your firmware's own driver.
2. `[FAIL]   Could not open Root directory: [14] Not Found` means that the UEFI NTFS driver provided by your motherboard is **crippled**, as it is unable to perform something as simple as [opening the NTFS volume](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs/blob/87f443140879ba0e3c73b4a895d64ec311ad1a8d/boot.c#L586-L590) which is a standard file system operation that a **proper** UEFI file system driver should always be able to accomplish.

So you have 2 options here:

1. Contact your motherboard's manufacturer to let them know that the NTFS driver they include in their firmware is crippled and that they should update it with a better version (or remove it so that users can use a driver that actually works).
2. Try to use exFAT instead of NTFS as the file system in Rufus. Unfortunately that means you will first have to create a **blank** UEFI:NTFS drive (First click on *Show advanced drive options* to show the advanced options, **then** select `UEFI:NTFS` under *Boot selection*, then select `exFAT` as the file system and click *START*) and then **manually** extract the Windows Server 2016 files onto that disk, as Rufus will not do that for you (exFAT is not enabled by default for Windows images because not all versions of Windows work with it, and as a matter of fact, I don't even know if Windows Server 2016 is compatible with exFAT boot). Hopefully by using exFAT instead of NTFS, and provided Windows Server 2016 is compatible with exFAT boot the embedded NTFS driver from your motherboard should no longer be an issue and instead the exFAT driver provided by Rufus will be loaded, which should be able to open the volume without error. I can't promise that this option will work though...

Oh and **please, please, please**, do provide the manufacturer and model of the motherboard you tried to use, where you encountered the error, so that consumers can find out what manufacturers use **crippled** NTFS drivers and stay well away from these products...

Comment: Thank you for the tips. My motherboard is a ASRock B365M Pro4. I am currently copying the files over and will let you know if it works.

Comment: I now get another error, which I have attached in the question.

Comment: I see your error, and the most likely explanation is that you forgot to extract the content of the ISO __manually__ after you created the blank UEFI:NTFS drive with the exFAT partition in Rufus. The error you get indicates that there is no `efi\boot\bootx64.efi` on the exFAT partition, but the official Windows Server 2016 ISOs most certainly contain one, so you most likely did not copy the content. You need to install something like 7-zip and then extract the content from your Windows Server ISO onto the exFAT partitition. Rufus will __not__ do this for you in this case.

Comment: there was in fact a bootx64.efi file on the drive, I even went into the drive and checked it myself.

Comment: Are you sure you checked the main exFAT partition and not the UEFI_NTFS partitions? Please be very mindful that you will __also__ find a `efi\boot\bootx64.efi` on the small partition that UEFI:NTFS created on your drive, but this is not the one I was talking about. As the author of UEFI:NTFS, I have never ever gotten a report of `[FAIL]   Could not locate 'efi\boot\bootx64.efi': [14] Not Found` that wasn't due to that file being missing on the main exFAT or NTFS partition. In other words, unless you see __TWO__ `efi\boot\bootx64.efi` files on your disk (one in each partition) this will fail.

Comment: Yep, there is a bootx64.efi in each partition.

Comment: Okay. Then can I ask you to please create an issue at https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues and recreate your USB from the Windows ISO (i.e. like you did the first time with NTFS as the file system) and copy/paste your full Rufus log in the issue you opened. This USB won't work, but the log will help me try to identify what the issue might be, as I would really like to get to the bottom of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with YUMI. You have also the Option to load the source media with *Try Unlisted ISO (Grub from RAM)*, just in case you encounter a similar conflict.

I installed Windows 7 with the option *Multiple Windows Vista/7/8/10 Installer -bootmgr*.